# Slow queries to AWS RDS MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, django, amazon-web-services, django-rest-framework, rds

Am building a project with Django REST Framework. I'm using Amazon RDS for my MySQL database, and for some reason the wait time on my calls are always around 200ms, if I connect to a local MySQL instance the time is around 8ms.

So first I thought it must be the connection time that is the problem, so I added 'CONN_MAX_AGE':60 to my database settings. This definitely made Django not create new connections looking at "SHOW PROCESSLIST;" on the DB, and brought the time down to about 190ms.

The thing is when I make queries to the RDS database vis HeidiSQL the time is around 16ms.

Anyone have any idea what is added all that time?